# Why is arcpy.ListUsers() not able to open SDE workspace?

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-pro, function, typeerror

I am working with ArcGIS Pro 2.1 and Python 3.6.2. and I am writing a script that involves the `arcpy.ListUsers()` function and whenever I run the code I receive the following error:

[image: arcpy.ListUsers() error]

The SDE workspace can be accessed I have tried the `arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()` and the function did not fail or receive an error message; I am also able to open the connection in Catalog.

What can I do to get past this issue (this function is necessary for my script, so it cannot be removed)?

*Note: The `arcpy.ListUsers()` function fails whether it is ran in the script or on its own.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
# import system modules
print("Importing system modules...")
import arcpy, os, shutil

# crete a temp folder to store a database connection
print("Checking for the temp directory...")
directory = r"P:\Python"
if not os.path.exists(directory):
    os.makedirs(directory)

# check for CGF database connection
print("Creating the database connection...")
if not arcpy.Exists(r"P:\Python\CGF_temp.sde"):
    # if non existent, create a connection
    arcpy.CreateDatabaseConnection_management(directory, "CGF_temp.sde", "SQL_SERVER", "###", "DATABASE_AUTH", "###",
                                          "###", "SAVE_USERNAME", "CGF")

# set workspace environments
# workspace must be a connection file to an ADMIN (sde) connection
print("Setting the workspace environments...")
arcpy.env.workspace = r"P:\Python\CGF_temp.sde"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
workspace = arcpy.env.workspace

# obtaining a list of connected users
print("Obtaining a list of connected users...")
users = arcpy.ListUsers("CGF_temp.sde")
print(users)
```

Comment: Could you perhaps post some of the code you have written? Maybe just up to where it fails? Have you tried running the script in ArcMap desktop and not Pro? I am still new to Pro, but have seen minor differences in the was things are called for the Pro licenses.

Comment: I added in the script that I have so far.  I have not tried running the script in Desktop as I have uninstalled it from my computer to get rid of the confusion with Python versions.  I am new to Pro as well and have noticed a few minor differences in the syntax.

Comment: Have you tried using the full path to the SDE connection file?

Comment: I have tried using the full path, I have also tried using "Database Connection/CGF_temp.sde" and I have tried using 'workspace'.  I end up getting the same error every time.

Comment: Have you tried Alex's answer below?

Comment: Yes, I just tried it, still no luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75520/discussion-between-keagan-allan-and-rosemary).

Comment: The documentation states that the function is only valid for connections with administrative rights to terminate user sessions.

Comment: @Vince, good point. When trying to call the `ListUsers` supplying a non-administrative connection, I get `RuntimeError: Connection information provided was for a non-administrative user`, so Rosemary seems to be using the admin connection.

Comment: Yes, I am using an admin connection.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are setting up the `arcpy.env.workspace` to be the path to the `.sde` connection file. When you run the `ListUsers`, it cannot find the `.sde` file inside the `.sde` file.

Instead of

`arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Temp\CGF_temp.sde"`

Set it to be

`arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Temp"`

Comment: I just changed the code to match your suggestion and I still receive the same error. With the ListUsers() function I am not calling on the workspace, I am only calling the .sde, so it should not affect the function finding the .sde. Should it?

Comment: According to the help it looks like it'll work with and without a `arcpy.env.workspace` set. Not sure what happens if you set both. But try each scenario: workspace set and nothing into ListUsers and viceversa.

Comment: @KHibma, you are right, it can work with and without setting the `arcpy.env.workspace`. However, in the question body, the code was to set up the `arcpy.env.workspace` to be inside the `.sde` file and `ListUsers` has received the `.sde` path again. If you set the `workspace` to be a path to an `.sde` file and then call `ListUsers()` without passing the path again, you'd get `TypeError: ListUsers() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sde_workspace'`. So you anyway need to pass either the full path or just the name of `.sde` file if you have already set the workspace folder.